# Accordion not hiding when changing to another section

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

In [this page](http://www.agi.cl/Detalles.aspx?Me_Tipo=101) I have got an accordion which does not work as well as I would like. When moving from one section to another I wish to hide the section I am leaving but it does not work that way. 
Any clue what I am missing ?

Comment: Please provide code snippets and/or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) illustrating the problem. If your page goes down, this question won't be able to help anyone else.

Comment: I'll do it next time, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You can still edit your question an add code. It's not too late!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line:

```
$('.panel-collapse').not(target).collapse("hide");
```

There is no element with the `.panel-collapse` class. Did you mean to use `.accordion-body` instead?

```
$('.accordion-body').not(target).collapse("hide");
```

Comment: Glad to hear it works! You should mark this as the answer then.